# Unable to import OpenCV even after successful installation for Python 3.7.6 (ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.)

Tags: python, opencv, dllimport

I have tried reinstalling all versions of Pythons and OpenCVs but for my use case, I need to stick with Tensorflow 1.15.0 which is supported by Python version 3.7.x. (with all the necessary MS VS C++ build tools with Visual Studio version 2019 also reinstalled to be safe)

So for now, I have `Python 3.7.6` with `opencv-contrib-python==4.5.2.52` installed on my machine at the moment. And for all combinations of Python and OpenCV, I simply get the below error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\aadak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I was wondering if anyone else has faced this particular sequence of error in line # 5 of `__init.py__` and how one can rectify this error.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: that's hard to debug. the error, issued by windows, does not come with information on *what* dll was tried. it could be any of a number of dlls that are required. build OpenCV with a minimal number of modules. see if it works. then include more modules in the build, until you hit a module that causes the issue. I'd recommend enabling groups of modules per compilation+install attempt (and keep track of which you added)

Comment: did you pip install also "opencv-python"?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Sure Chris, I'll give that a go.

Comment: @Miki Yes, I have that installed too. But even then, I'm getting the aforementioned error. :(